# Function to check similarity of a string with a list of strings

Tags: cpu-word, similarity

I have a collection of similar strings in a bucket and have multiple such buckets. What kind of function should I use on the strings to compare a random string with the buckets to find out which bucket it belongs to?

To clarify on each entity in the bucket, it is a sentence that can have multiple words.

An example:

Consider the list of strings in the bucket: 
 1. round neck black t-shirt 
 2. printed tee shirt 
 3. brown polo t-shirt

If we have as input, "blue high neck t-shirt", we want to check if this can be added to the same bucket. This might be a simpler example but consider doing this for a bucket of let's say 100s of strings.

Any reference to an article or paper will be really helpful.

Comment: create a meta string which represents a bucket using the sample strings in that bucket. Now, if you have 'n' buckets you will have 'n' such strings. On the query string you could use get the edit distance between each such representative and assign it to the bucket that has it closest to.

Comment: @82Tuskers That is a good idea but the point I am struggling with is how to create a meta string? To clarify on each entity in the bucket, it is a sentence that can have multiple words

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am thinking about two kinds of similarities: syntactic and semantic.

**1) Syntactic**

- [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) can be used to measure distance between two sequences (of characters)
- [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) can be used to increase match probability. There are various implementations (e.g. [here](https://stemmersnet.codeplex.com/)). You get the stem (or root) word for your random string and compare with stems from your buckets. Of course, buckets stems should be precomputed for efficiency.

**2) Semantic**

- for general info you can read the [article from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity)
- for actual implementation you can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11835/WordNet-based-semantic-similarity-measurement) from CodeProject. It is based on WordNet, a great ontology for English language that stores concepts in synsets and also provides various relations between these synsets.

To get more details you should tell us what kind of similarity you need.

**[edit]**

Based on provided information, I think you can do something like this:

1) split all strings in words => random string will be named Array1 and current bucket Array2

2) compute similarity as number_of_common_words(Array1, Array2) / count(Array2)

3) choose maximum similarity

Specificity may also be increased, by adding points to position match: Array1[i] = Array2[i]

For better performance I would store buckets as Hash tables, Dictionary etc., so that existence check is done in O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This is more of a syntactic requirement. Stemming will definitely be useful in this case while edit distance may not be as we are only concerned about exact match and edit distance will result in more false positives.

It would be more helpful if you have any ideas around a function that can help assign a match score to the string with the bucket.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? It will help provide a better answer.

Comment: Sure. Here is an example:

Consider the list of strings in the bucket:
1. round neck black t-shirt
2. printed tee shirt
3. brown polo t-shirt

If we have as input, "blue high neck t-shirt", we want to check if this can be added to the same bucket.

This might be a simpler example but consider doing this for a bucket of let's say 100s of strings.

Comment: I think it is easier to update the initial question since virtually there is no limit to the length and also allows for advanced formatting :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Added it to the main question.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines but I thought this was the basic approach and can use some statistical function to find the similarity but I think trying out with the basic approach with some dataset will help me analyze how to go about it in long run.

Thanks for the all the help.